# button, label is getting hide when i scroll table view up and down

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a `tableview`, and in each cell I have one `button` called drop down. So when user presses any option in my drop down - the hidden elements like one more drop down, one name label, one save button will be visible. So again when user presses my save button again those elements will be hidden. Now the issues is when I select my button in two or three cells and if I scroll up and down automatically which and all cell showing the elements that and all getting hide. I need to show which and all cell is clicked and showed the elements.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartDetailsCell", for: indexPath) as! CartDetailsCell
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
 let notClicked = !selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath)
        print(notClicked)
        cell.noOfQtyOuterView.isHidden = notClicked
        cell.saveDataButnOtlet.isHidden = notClicked
        cell.noOfQtyButnOutlet.isHidden = notClicked
}

 @IBAction func dropDownButnClick(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let button = sender as? UIButton else {
            return
        }
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: button.tag, section: 0)
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CartDetailsCell
            dropDown.anchorView = button
            dropDown.dataSource = ["Edit", "Cancel"]
dropDown.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index: Int, item: String) in
                switch index {


                case 0:

                    cell.noOfQtyOuterView.isHidden = false
                    cell.saveDataButnOtlet.isHidden = false
                    cell.noOfComboOuterViewButn.isHidden = false



                case 2:
}
}
```

Comment: what is selectedIndexPaths ? where you are adding data to selectedIndexPaths ?

Comment: On tapping on the button the drop down view appears and on selecting a particular option from that drop down. The UI need to be changed is that the requirement?

Comment: When and how do you set the button's tag? (btw. it's kind of a dirty solution, I recommend to use the delegate pattern to identify cells instead of view tags)

Comment: @Anuraj  not Full Ui, that particular cell i need to show my elements like one label , one save button. After user edit some ting and they will press save button ..then that both elements will be disappera..ist fine..but now when i select any option from drop down.and when my label, button is showing and if i move the table view to up and down..then again ist coming to normal state...like that two elements was again hidden

Comment: @BencePattogato like this  `cell.saveDataButnOtlet.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.noOfComboOuterViewButn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.noOfQtyButnOutlet.tag = indexPath.row`

Comment: When u scroll up and down the cellForRow gets called. In you cell for row you have implemented  certain condition thats gets executed thereby changing the .hidden property  of saveDataButnOtlet etc.

Comment: only this part is there for that all elements `let notClicked = !selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath)
        print(notClicked)
        cell.noOfQtyOuterView.isHidden = notClicked
        cell.saveDataButnOtlet.isHidden = notClicked
        cell.noOfQtyButnOutlet.isHidden = notClicked`

Comment: What do you mean by "only this part is there for that all elements" ??

Comment: Any extra (data source) array like `selectedIndexPaths` is horrible. Put the `selected` information into the **model**.

Comment: You are not updating array when button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

**Once the button is hidden it will never be un-hidden until you explicitly make it unhidden.**

"Now the issues is when i select my button in two or three cells and if i scroll up and down automatically which and all cell showing the elements that and al getting hide"

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartDetailsCell", for: indexPath) as! CartDetailsCell

As you are using the cell with the hidden button is reused, it will make the button remain hidden for remaining cells

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use following pattern, will save you time and you'll have a more reusable and pretty code:

```
protocol CartDetailsCellDelegate: class {
    func didTouchDropDownButton(in cell: CartDetailsCell)
    ....
}

final class CartDetailsCell: UITableViewCell {
    ....
    weak var delegate: CartDetailsCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func didTouchDropDownButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.didTouchDropDownButton(in: self)
    }
    ...
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    cell.delegate = self
    ...
}

extension ViewController: CartDetailsCellDelegate {
    func didTouchDropDownButton(in cell: CartDetailsCell) {
        // Do your stuff here, you have the cell, don't have to play with tags
    }
}
```